# Are human-like robots animate or inanimate?

Tags: meaning, syntax

There are constructions for existence that depend on animated object or not.

鳥がいます - There is a bird (animate).

椅子があります - There is a chair (inanimate).

How do you treat human-like robots? Are they animate or inanimate? Is it related to biological nature of the object or to ability to move? What about cars? They can move as well but have no limbs.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate, thank you for pointing this.